# Firewall settings are they available on Microsoft Azure portal

Tags: azure, cloud, firewall, trial

Trying out the Azure to see if its a good fit for some projects with the Free Trial Version. Question is can I configure firewall settings on the free version?

Comment: It would help if you'd tell us what services you're using

Answer (score 0):

Firewalling is a little complicated on the portal at the moment.

While it is possible to administer an existing Security Group on either a Network Interface or a Virtual Network, it is not currently possible to create a Security Group from within the portal.

This means that you need to use the `New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup` to create a security group, once that is done you can assign and administer it from within the portal.

This is going on the presumption that you are using the new portal and Azure Resource Management VMs, Vnets etc. The old portal is considerably more fragmented with regards to firewalls. If you are using the old portal, tell us what you're using and we can help you figure it out.